# Expressing the difference between two rates

Tags: interpretation

I have what I hope is a simple question about interpreting rates.

Let's say I have two populations, and I know the rate of at which members of both are a particular demographic. I'll use gender.

Let's say I know that 60 / 100 people from Group 1 are men and 50 / 100 people in Group 2 are men.

Can I say that the likelihood that a random person from Group 1 is a man is 10 percent higher than from Group 2?

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: This is a language question, aiming to avoid ambiguity.  You might prefer to say "the probability that a random person from Group 1 is a man is 10 percentage points higher than from Group 2"

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot say that because 10% of 50% is 5% so 10% higher than 50% = 50% + 5% = 55% and not 60%.